# Realtor Credit or Kickback

Tags: united-states, income-tax, real-estate, first-time-home-buyer

Its our first home purchase in Maryland, USA.

Our realtor agreed to give us 2% kickback (towards closing cost) and she keeps 1% from the 3% commission she gets.

If base price of our home is 400K, shouldn't we be getting $8K from her? She is giving us less than $7K.

Is it because of taxes or something else?

Comment: Ask for an accounting of the amount. i.e. to see her calculations.

Comment: My realtor just informed me that 15% goes to the agency which she represents, in this case its ReMax.

Comment: Did she prorate the 15%? It's $1800 so did she take off $1200 or the entire amount? Still, she should have made the distribution clear up-front. The amount she owes the agency is her responsibility, not yours.

Answer (score 3):

Since you said that the agency she works at takes 15% of her 3% commission it looks like what happened was...

From the 400k 3% goes to the Realtor so $12,000

From that $12,000 15% goes to the Broker so now she only has $10,200

From that $10,200 she is giving you 66.66% which is around 6,800

And she is keeping 3,400

(You could also calculate it by taking the $8,000 which was 2% of the real estate agents commission and take 15% away from that - gives the same number $6,800)

Since I don't have the exact numbers that are my best assumption, but that is not a big sum that the realtor is getting. Unless this was a deal that was very quick or the agent was bad/didn't do a lot of work, I would not see this a very fair for the agent. That amount of money is similar to small lease/rent deals, not deals with buying 400k homes. So I would be grateful to the agent regardless.